# Is it possible to make chartjs charts scrollable?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to make charts of my analytics data using chart.js. Here's a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/LzFh7/).

Currently it is with default sample data. What I want to do is something like this, with infinite scrolling from left to right:

[image]

How can I implement that behavior here?

```
var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};
        var lineChartData = {
            labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
            datasets : [
                {
                    label: "My First dataset",
                    fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
                },
                {
                    label: "My Second dataset",
                    fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
                }
            ]

        }


        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
            responsive: true
        });
```

Comment: Sorry, I (personally) have no suggestions about chart.js
And suggestion of competitor products are actually prohibited on this site :)

Our product (see my profile) has options which you need, it could fit you.

Comment: I would love to have an answer for that! Did you managed to figure it out?

Answer (score -1):

[Chart.js](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.Zoom.js) came up with their official plugin to this

Comment: This may theoretically answer the question, but it would be best to include the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and provide the link for reference. [Link-dominated answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) can become invalid through [link rot](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).